# ReactJS: How to access refs of child component?

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

I'm writing the code in CoffeeScript since I've been writing React with it.
Here is the basic structure.

```
{ div, input } = React.DOM

Outer = React.createClass
  render: ->
    div { id: 'myApp' },
      Inner()

Inner = React.createClass
  render: ->
    input { id: 'myInput', ref: 'myInput' }
```

I have a `toggle` method on my Outer class which is triggered by pressing a shortcut. It toggles the visibility of my app.
When my app is toggled from hidden to shown, I want to focus on the input.

Now the toggle methods look more or less like this:

```
Outer = React.createClass
  render: ->
     ......

  hide: ->
    @setState { visible: no }

  show: ->
    @setState { visible: yes }

    $('#myInput').focus() # jQuery
    # I want to do something like
    # @refs.myInput.getDOMNode().focus()
    # But @refs here is empty, it doesn't contain the refs in Inner

  toggle: ->
    if @state.visible
      @hide()
    else
      @show()
```

How do I do this then?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Accessing the `refs` of a child breaks encapsulation since `refs` are not considered part of a component's API. Instead you should expose a function on `Inner` that can be called by a parent component, calling it `focus` might make sense.

Also, focus the element in `componentDidUpdate` to ensure rendering is complete:

```
{ div, input } = React.DOM

Outer = React.createClass
  render: ->
    div { id: 'myApp' },
      Inner({ref: 'inner'})

  componentDidUpdate: (prevProps, prevState) ->
    # Focus if `visible` went from false to true
    if (@state.visible && !prevState.visible)
      @refs.inner.focus()

  hide: ->
    @setState { visible: no }

  show: ->
    @setState { visible: yes }

  toggle: ->
    if @state.visible
      @hide()
    else
      @show()

Inner = React.createClass
  focus: ->
    @refs.myInput.getDOMNode().focus()

  render: ->
    input { id: 'myInput', ref: 'myInput' }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can chain refs, so if you pull an element by ref, you can grab refs inside that element:

Defining your `Outer` class as

`Outer = React.createClass
  render: ->
    div { id: 'myApp' },
      Inner {ref: 'inner'}`

would let you then grab the input with `@refs.inner.refs.myInput.getDOMNode()` to call `focus` on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I prefer @ssorallen 's solution, which looks cleaner to me.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the solution is simple, you can tell the input to autofocus, which in React focuses it when it's rendered.

```
Inner = React.createClass
  render: ->
    input { ref: 'myInput', autoFocus: true }
```

In general, you should pass a prop to the Inner component, and in [componentDidUpdate](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate) you can do:

```
if @props.something
    @refs.myInput.getDOMNode().focus()
```

Comment: AutoFocus doesn't work for me. Actually I just thought about `componentDidUpdate` and tried something similar to what you suggested and it worked. But I really want to know whether there is an easy way to access refs of child components. The refs example on React Doc puts an input inside the top component, but in reality the inputs are usually nested within sub-components.

Comment: Refs are only usable in the component where they're defined.  If they were accessible by any child component, you'd have to assume your name for a ref wouldn't clash with any other ref.  You'd also have to check every other component if you wanted to remove a ref, or change it.  These assumptions and looking all over the place are best avoided.